# Doing track stand while sitting?

Tags: trackstand

I have been trying to do "track stands" while sitting down. Standing up makes it harder to balance and doesnt feel right.

Is it possible to do a track stand while sitting down? Should I just stop trying this and learn to do it the right way?

This reminds me a bit about how I didnt use the "home row" to touch type for a very long time, then I concentrated on "doing it right" and was surprised by how easy it was to learn.

Answer (score 4):

I probably don't do "proper" track stands since I don't ride a fixed gear bike, but if you can find a bit of a hill at a stop then you can kind-of-sort-of do a track stand (you pedal up the hill and let gravity pull you back down). Sometimes the crown of the road is enough…

That said, I always sit, I didn't know you were supposed to stand, so I'd say keep working on it!

Comment: Sure, I can sit and do a track stand for several minutes. So it's definitely doable. Just takes some practice to work on your balance. Finding the right food position is key, I typically stop with the pedals at the same level and cranks parallel to the road.

Comment: Indeed, I think you've got to keep the pedals roughly parallel to the road surface. That is what gives you the control, even with a freewheel/hub.